# Refactoring code that contains multiple if conditions

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, design-patterns, refactoring

Here is some code I've written to save a UrlEntity :

```
public UrlEntity saveUrlEntity(String longUrl, LocalDate dateAdded) {

    int urlLength = longUrl.length();
    if (urlLength >= Constants.MAX_LONG_URL_LENGTH) {
        throw new LongUrlLengthExceededException("URL with length " + urlLength + " exceeds the max length of " + Constants.MAX_LONG_URL_LENGTH + " characters");
    } else {

        List<UrlEntity> urlEntity = urlRepository.findByLongUrl(longUrl);
        if (urlEntity.size() > 0) {
            return urlEntity.get(0);
        } else {
            final String shortUrl = urlShorten.shortenURL(longUrl);
            if (urlRepository.findFirstByShortUrl(shortUrl).isPresent()) {
                logger.error("A short short URL collision occured for long URL: " + longUrl + " with generated short URL" + shortUrl);
                throw new ShortUrlCollisionException("A short URL collision occured");
            } else {
                logger.info("Shortened URL: " + shortUrl);

                final UrlEntity urlEntityToSave = new UrlEntity(dateAdded, longUrl, shortUrl);

                return urlRepository.save(urlEntityToSave);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The above code exists in a service class and looks unnecessarily complex. I'm attempting to refactor so that the intent is clear. This is a basic refactoring I've written:

```
public UrlEntity saveUrlEntity(String longUrl, LocalDate dateAdded) {

    int urlLength = longUrl.length();
    if (urlLength >= Constants.MAX_LONG_URL_LENGTH) {
        throw new LongUrlLengthExceededException("URL with length " + urlLength + " exceeds the max length of " + Constants.MAX_LONG_URL_LENGTH + " characters");
    } else {
        List<UrlEntity> urlEntity = urlRepository.findByLongUrl(longUrl);
        if (urlEntity.size() > 0) {
            return urlEntity.get(0);
        } else {
            return saveUrlEntityValue(longUrl, dateAdded);
        }
    }
}

private UrlEntity saveUrlEntityValue(String longUrl, LocalDate dateAdded){
    final String shortUrl = urlShorten.shortenURL(longUrl);
    if (urlRepository.findFirstByShortUrl(shortUrl).isPresent()) {
        logger.error("A short short URL collision occured for long URL: " + longUrl + " with generated short URL" + shortUrl);
        throw new ShortUrlCollisionException("A short URL collision occured");
    } else {
        logger.info("Shortened URL: " + shortUrl);

        final UrlEntity urlEntityToSave = new UrlEntity(dateAdded, longUrl, shortUrl);

        return urlRepository.save(urlEntityToSave);
    }
}
```

This refactoring does not improve the code substantially. Is there a code pattern or idiomatic way to refactor the method `saveUrlEntity`? I'm using `Java11`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is very subjective, but... Since most of your `if` statements are guard/short-circuit clauses, which `throw` or `return`, there is no need to use `else`. I think this simple change makes the code much more readable.

```
public UrlEntity saveUrlEntity(String longUrl, LocalDate dateAdded) {

    final int urlLength = longUrl.length();
    if (urlLength >= Constants.MAX_LONG_URL_LENGTH) {
        throw new LongUrlLengthExceededException("URL with length " + urlLength + " exceeds the max length of " + Constants.MAX_LONG_URL_LENGTH + " characters");
    }

    final List<UrlEntity> urlEntity = urlRepository.findByLongUrl(longUrl);
    if (urlEntity.size() > 0) {
        return urlEntity.get(0);
    }

    final String shortUrl = urlShorten.shortenURL(longUrl);
    if (urlRepository.findFirstByShortUrl(shortUrl).isPresent()) {
        logger.error("A short short URL collision occured for long URL: " + longUrl + " with generated short URL" + shortUrl);
        throw new ShortUrlCollisionException("A short URL collision occured");
    }

    logger.info("Shortened URL: " + shortUrl);
    final UrlEntity urlEntityToSave = new UrlEntity(dateAdded, longUrl, shortUrl);
    return urlRepository.save(urlEntityToSave);
}
```

I'd also recommend replacing `urlEntity.size() > 0` with `!urlEntity.isEmpty()`.

The method does seem to be doing several things, which violates the Single Responsibility Principle; you might want to think about breaking that out better.

Answer (score 1):

If you use `throw new` or `return` you do not need the else condition because the method ends like

```
public UrlEntity saveUrlEntity(String longUrl, LocalDate dateAdded) {

    int urlLength = longUrl.length();
    if (urlLength >= Constants.MAX_LONG_URL_LENGTH) {
        throw new LongUrlLengthExceededException("URL with length " + urlLength + " exceeds the max length of " + Constants.MAX_LONG_URL_LENGTH + " characters");
    }
    
    List<UrlEntity> urlEntity = urlRepository.findByLongUrl(longUrl);
    if (urlEntity.size() > 0) {
        return urlEntity.get(0);
    }
    
    final String shortUrl = urlShorten.shortenURL(longUrl);
    if (urlRepository.findFirstByShortUrl(shortUrl).isPresent()) {
        logger.error("A short short URL collision occured for long URL: " + longUrl + " with generated short URL" + shortUrl);
        throw new ShortUrlCollisionException("A short URL collision occured");
    }
    
    logger.info("Shortened URL: " + shortUrl);
    final UrlEntity urlEntityToSave = new UrlEntity(dateAdded, longUrl, shortUrl);
    return urlRepository.save(urlEntityToSave);
}
```